# Personalizar .read() e .write() em Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou Começando a aprender Python e me surgiu um duvida usando `with` para abrir arquivos, é possível passar argumentos para os métodos `arquivo.read()` para ler uma linha e pular para a linha de baixo quando é encontrado um TAB ou espaços?

Para a escrita acredito que `arquivo.write(conteudo1, "\t", conteudo2)` resolveria.

Comment: E se houver conteúdo após o espaço em branco?

Comment: Mas a intenção é essa, fazer pesquisas personalizadas vamos supor que eu tenha um arquivo de um time de futebol e queira pegar só o nome dos atletas.

Comment: Acredito que precisará fazer manualmente mesmo. Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [mcve]?